# Remove first child in javascript

Tags: javascript, element

I'm trying to remove the first `li` in an `ol` using the DOM `removeChild()`. But for some reason it doesn't work.

This is my javascript:

```
document.getElementById('queue').removeChild(
    document.getElementById('queue').childNodes[0]
);
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<ol id="queue">
    <li>Surprised Kitty (Original)<span class="nodisplay">0Bmhjf0rKe8</span></li></ol>
```

I tried alerting the `childNodes[0]`, and it returns `[Object Text]`, which seems a bit weird, when I was expecting just the object.

Hope I've been clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Between the `<ol id="queue">` and the `<li>` tag are spaces and a line break. These make up a text node. The first child of the `#queue` element is therefore a text node.

You can use the [`.children`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t71) property instead of `.childNodes`, it only considers element nodes, or iterate over all child nodes until you find the first `li` node, like [suggested by dystroy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14294530/218196).

Comment: @Locercus No, it is native. Just use `document.getElementById('queue').children[0]`

Comment: No it isn't.... jQuery has a `.children` method as well, but that's not what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 16):

Try this one-liner:

```js
document.getElementById('queue').removeChild(document.getElementById('queue').getElementsByTagName('li')[0]);
```

With expanded explanation:

```js
var queue = document.getElementById('queue'); // Get the list whose id is queue.
var elements = queue.getElementsByTagName('li'); // Get HTMLCollection of elements with the li tag name.
queue.removeChild(elements[0]); // Remove the child from queue that is the first li element.
```

Comment: The first child element is a text with a line break. With this line of  code you get 'li' elements only.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! :) dystroy gave an answer describing this.

Comment: What i meant is that people are more likely to upvote your answer if you provide an explanation. Not just a code fragment.

Answer (score 4):

remove all lists contained by queue:

```
var list=document.getElementById('queue');

list.removeChild(list.getElementsByTagName('li')[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Child nodes aren't just the elements you think about but also the text nodes. You can iterate over the nodes and remove the first `LI`.

```
var p = document.getElementById('queue');
for (var i=0; i<p.childNodes.length; i++) {
   if (p.childNodes[i].tagName=='LI') {
       p.removeChild(p.childNodes[i]);
       break;
   }
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/vBP6b/)

Note that this is more an explanation than the most practical solution. Javascript has other iteration solutions for you, among them [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.tagName), so you may do this :

```
var p = document.getElementById('queue');
p.removeChild(p.getElementsByTagName('li')[0]);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/wrcur/)

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: For the record, I see that Alex mentioned getElementsByTagName before my edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this single line of code. Which will delete always first child element of the parent.

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('#queue').firstElementChild.remove();
```

HTML:

```
<ol id="queue">
    <li>
        Surprised Kitty (Original)
        <span class="nodisplay">0Bmhjf0rKe8</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Most simple solution i think