# Javascript equivalent to Jquerys :first / :last

Tags: javascript

I am working at removing jQuery from my workflow, instead using vanilla Javascript. In the following, I am struggling to find a solution to `:first` and `:last`. I've tried a few options, including `.firstChild` / `.lastChild` - nothing I have found works.

In jQuery, I have:

```
firstInput = $('form#enquiry-form input[type=text]:not("#first_name"):first'),
lastInput = $('form#enquiry-form input[type=text]:not("#first_name"):last')
```

In vanilla JS, I have:

```
firstInput =  document.querySelector('form#enquiry-form input[type="text"]:not(#first_name)').firstChild,
lastInput = document.querySelector('form#enquiry-form input[type="text"]:not(#first_name)').lastChild
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove first child in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294518/remove-first-child-in-javascript)

Comment: `:first` and `:last` aren't the first and last child. They're the first and last items that match the rest of the selector.

Comment: You're not looking for a *JavaScript* equivalent of `:first`/`:last`, you're looking for a ***DOM*** (or CSS) equivalent of it. JavaScript is a language. jQuery is a library for doing DOM operations.¹ If you want to stop using jQuery, you need to look for how to do the things you need to do with the DOM or CSS. (¹ Before someong "well actually"s me: yes, it also has a couple of minor non-DOM utility features. But that's not what it's mainly about.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/:first/) and [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/:last/) give you the first or last *matching element* (element that matches the selector).

For `:first`, that's what [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) gives you, so just:

```
firstInput =  document.querySelector('form#enquiry-form input[type="text"]:not(#first_name)');
```

There's no DOM equivalent of `:last` other than getting the list and grabbing the last entry from it:

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll('form#enquiry-form input[type="text"]:not(#first_name)');
lastInput = list.length ? list[list.length - 1] : null;
```

There's an [`at` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method) making its way through the JavaScript process (it's at Stage 3, which is pretty far along). One can hope that it would be adopted by DOM collections as well (though I haven't heard that it will, but keep reading). If that happens, that code would get simpler:

```
// IF/WHEN `at` is adopted in DOM lists
lastInput = document.querySelectorAll('form#enquiry-form input[type="text"]:not(#first_name)').at(-1);
```

Or it may be that the [`NodeList`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist) and [`HTMLCollection`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection) interfaces start handling negative indexing via `item` (`at` was originally going to be `item` in hopes of unifying this aspect of arrays and DOM lists, but unfortunately that's not possible).

It's not clear at present whether either `at` or a negative index for `item` will necessarily be supported by DOM Lists. So you're probably best off having a utility function for it which you can hopefully update at some point.

Comment: You can use `list.pop()` instead of writing the conditional and index.

Comment: @Barmar - With a `NodeList`?

Comment: Oops, forgot about that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there is always `Array.prototype.pop.apply(list)` :P but to be clear, I prefer just getting the `length - 1` item.

Comment: @VLAZ - `pop` modifies the target, you can't use it on `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise the length was immutable for `NodeList`s.

Comment: @VLAZ - It's the delete operation on the index that fails in Chrome, but yeah, basically their list contents are immutable. `HTMLCollection` is live so naturally changes to it can't happen (although I had to try it to be sure it didn't remove the element from the DOM ;-) ).